# How to fix automatic image movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I created an image slideshow with crossfade, which cycles automatically every second. The cross-fade works fine, with everytime the image fades in and the old fades out, its top position is higher than the previous. Then, at the final image, the image positions reset.

Steps:
1. Margin-top: -575px 
2. Margin-top: -600px (i assume) 
3. Margin-top: -625px (again, I assume)

You get the idea..., it's rising and then it resets at the first image

The jQuery

```
$(function() {

    var slides = [$("#image1"),$("#image2"), $("#image3"), $("#image4"), $("#image5")];        
    var slidePos = 0;

    setInterval(function() {

        if (slidePos < slides.length-1) {
            slides[slidePos].animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 1000);

            slides[slidePos+1].animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 1000, function() {
                slidePos++;
            });

        } else {
            marginCalc = 575;

            slides[slidePos].animate({
                opacity: "0"
            }, 1000);

            slidePos = 0;

            slides[slidePos].animate({
                opacity: "1"
            }, 1000);
        }
    }, 3000);
});
```

The relevant CSS

```
.slideshow-container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

.transparent-image {
    position: relative;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -50.5%;
}

#image1 {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Its unclear what the problem is, do you want the image to rise or is this an unintended effect?

Comment: The rise is an unintended effect, it should just stay in its place.

Answer (score 0):

is there a link for showing your question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MailCarrier/bvu3shka/19/ --- That link should work